# How can I sort Safari bookmarks in Lion?

Tags: safari, bookmarks, sort

I used Bookmarkdog in Snow Leopard and Lion but since I'm using iCloud that app no longer works and its successor BookMaster does not seem to be doing the sorting like Bookmarkdog used to do.

- What others tools are using to sort Safari's bookmarks?
- How do you keep your Safari Bookmarks sorted?

Answer (score 2):

**Bookmarks bar**:

- Bookmarks in the **bookmarks bar** can be sorted using drag-and-drop.

**Bookmarks menu**:

- When you toggle **Show All Bookmarks** <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and click on collections → bookmarks menu, you may manually sort bookmarks which are located in the **bookmarks menu**.

You can sort bookmarks alphabetically using [SafariSort](http://www.safarisort.com/) (free). This applications works with the latest version of Safari in Lion (5.1.4, march 2012) and sorts folders and 'simple' bookmarks seperately. Unfortunately, such an option is not provided with Safari out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Bookmark Sorter](http://www.softpinch.com/bookmarksorter) on Lion and like it a lot. It installs itself as a Safari service and almost feels like sorting from within Safari itself. It can also run as a background process and automatically sort new bookmarks. It is a great little utility.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SafariSort](http://www.safarisort.com) its super fast and free.

> SafariSort will alphabetically sort your Safari bookmarks in just one click! All your folders, sub-folders and bookmarks will be sorted enabling you to actually find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I keep all my bookmarks in (subfolders of folders of) the bookmark bar, and use the excellent free service called [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) to sync them across computers. Unlike iCloud, Xmarks allows me to sync across browsers and operating systems (I do use iCloud for bookmark sync with the iPhone).

Never had any sorting issues to date: my custom (non-alphabetical) sort order seems to be preserved. But then again, who cares about the sort order, when Quicksilver instantly finds any bookmark upon typing a few characters of its name or URL...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem where sorting bookmarks in Safari, manually or using an app, does not work - the sorted bookmarks automatically get re-sorted in a messed up random order. This is iCloud randomly rearranging bookmarks when it syncs.

So I don't use iCloud for bookmark syncing, xmarks is excellent, free for PCs, laptops etc, and only $12 a year for the premium version which covers mobile devices.

Comment: Adding a link about where to get Xmarks from would increase the value of your answer.